# What could be run configuration for eclipse IDE for protractor-cucumber-typescript framework

Tags: javascript, eclipse, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am very new to protractor-cucumber-typescript framework. Is there any way if we can launch tests under this framework using run configuration of eclipse IDE ?
I dont want to use cmd every time to invoke the tests

Kindly let me know.

Link for framework: https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwoing:

1. Click on "Run configuration"
2. Configure Protractor in "Run configuration" and click on Run
3. Browse workspace to select cli.js (Usual cli.js path: Current Project>node_modules>Protractor>built>cli.js)

[Refer this link for more details](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor)